# Finding a combination of + and * operation to reach a target value

Tags: java, debugging, math, binary-tree

I am currently trying to solve a problem where we take multiple positive integers in one line and a single integer in the second line and find the mathematical operations to reach that value

example:

[image]

I kind of got stuck on the implementation of the N method I managed to get the L method working

N method is doing multiplication before addition just like normal math

L method is doing the mathimatical calculation from left to right without worrying about doing the multiplacation first
here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.Character;
import java.lang.StringBuilder;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Arithmetic{

    public static String operandBuilder = "";
    public static boolean isPossible = false;

    public static void main(String[] args){

        String inputNumbers;
        String[] stringSplitter = null;
        int[] numbers = null;
        char operation;
        String targetOp;
        int i, target;
        int length = 0;

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(scanner.hasNextLine()){

            inputNumbers = scanner.nextLine();
            // Takes in user input and makes it useable
            targetOp = scanner.nextLine();
            operation = targetOp.charAt(targetOp.length() - 1);
            targetOp = targetOp.substring(0, targetOp.length() - 2);
            operation = Character.toUpperCase(operation);
            target = Integer.parseInt(targetOp);

            // Turns the input numbers into a string, and removes all occurances of spaces
            stringSplitter = null;
            stringSplitter = inputNumbers.split(" ");  
            length = stringSplitter.length;

            // Initializes a new int array with a size that can hold the inputted numbers
            numbers = null;
            numbers = new int[length];

            // Fill the int array with contents from the string array
            for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
                numbers[i] = Integer.parseInt(stringSplitter[i]);
            }

            // If the user specified L operation, run that method. Otherwise, print error
            if(operation == 'L'){
                lrOperation(numbers, target, 0, 0);
            }else if(operation == 'N'){ 
                System.out.println("You printed N!");
            }else{
               System.err.println("ERROR: Please enter L or N for operation only");
            }

            // If the method adds anything to operand, it found a correct answer. The program prints that answer
            // Otherwise, it prints impossible.
            if(operandBuilder.length() > 0){
                System.out.println(operation + " " + (new StringBuilder(operandBuilder).reverse().toString()));
            }else{
                System.out.println(operation + " " + target + " impossible");
            }
            operandBuilder = "";
        }
        // Close the scanner, effectively ending the program
        scanner.close();

    }

    /* Recursively finds any possible solution for LHS solving 
       @param numbers - An int array which stores the numbers to be used
              target  - The int that the program is trying to find a calculation to hit
              sum     - Recursively stores the current sum of previous recursions
              depth   - Keeps track of what depth level the recursion is currently at
       @return boolean - Returns true if a possible calculation is found                  */
    public static boolean lrOperation(int[] numbers, int target, int sum, int depth){

        // If depth is higher than the length of numbers, return false
        if(depth >= numbers.length + 1){
            return false;
        }

        // Gets a digit length of current number to be used later
        int length = String.valueOf(numbers[depth]).length();

        // Checks to see if the current calculation is over the target
        if(!((sum * numbers[depth]) > target) || !((sum + numbers[depth]) > target)){

            // Checks to see if this if this current number is the last in inputs
            if(depth == numbers.length - 1){
                // If any current calculations are on target, return true and begin building the operandString
                if(sum + numbers[depth] == target){

                    isPossible = true;
                    if(length == 1){
                        operandBuilder += numbers[depth];
                    }else{
                        operandBuilder += new StringBuilder(Integer.toString(numbers[depth])).reverse().toString();
                    }
                    operandBuilder += " + ";
                    return true;
                }
                if(sum * numbers[depth] == target){
                    System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
                    System.out.println("Curr: " + numbers[depth]);
                    int temp = sum * numbers[depth];
                    System.out.println("Sum * Curr: " + temp);
                    isPossible = true;
                    if(length == 1){
                        operandBuilder += numbers[depth];
                    }else{
                        operandBuilder += new StringBuilder(Integer.toString(numbers[depth])).reverse().toString();
                    }
                    operandBuilder += " * ";
                    return true;
                }   
            }else{            
                // Checks to see if the next calculation is over the target or not. If under, keep recurring.
                if(!(sum + numbers[depth] > target)){
                    if (lrOperation(numbers, target, sum + numbers[depth], depth + 1)){
                        // Flag will be thrown if calculation found in previous recursion. Begin building string recursively
                        if(isPossible){
                            if(length == 1){
                                operandBuilder += numbers[depth];
                            }else{
                                operandBuilder += new StringBuilder(Integer.toString(numbers[depth])).reverse().toString();
                            }
                            if(depth > 0){
                                operandBuilder += " + ";
                            }
                        }
                        return true;
                    }                
                }
                // Checks to see if the next calculation is over the target or not. If under, keep recurring.
                if(!(sum * numbers[depth] > target)){
                    if(depth == 0){
                        sum = 1;
                    }
                    if (lrOperation(numbers, target, sum * numbers[depth], depth + 1)){
                        // Flag will be thrown if calculation found in previous recursion. Begin building string recursively
                        if(isPossible){
                            if(length == 1){
                                operandBuilder += numbers[depth];
                            }else{
                                operandBuilder += new StringBuilder(Integer.toString(numbers[depth])).reverse().toString();
                            }
                            if(depth > 0){
                                operandBuilder += " * ";
                            }
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                }              
            }
        }
        return false;
    }




    }
```

**any help would be appreciated**

Comment: Isn't your binary tree approach just brute force in disguise? Your tree will have as many leaf nodes as the number of candidates brute force will test.

Comment: but you don't have to go to the head of the tree to re calculate. u can go to the previous branch and look at the opposite direction. I will also implement a min and max method to see if the answer is in range

Comment: but you are right maybe I should use DFS Algorithm

Comment: What is the L and what is the N method? In any case, you need to be more detailed with your exact question, is it stands it is overly broad

Comment: You need to specify the limits, because the approach for a problem with the limit of 15 numbers would be different from an approach for a problem with 15,000 numbers. The problem looks like something you may have found on spoj, topcoder, etc. If you could post a link to full problem description, that would be helpful too.

Comment: limits aren't specified but I am assuming that we won't be doing more than 100 numbers. I also have specified the N method and the L method